# Is there a probabilistic proof of Erdős-Szekeres theorem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was talking about the Erdős-Szekeres theorem, which states that in a sequence with $mn+1$ terms, there either exists a monotonically increasing subsequence with length $m+1$ or a monotonically decreasing subsequence with length $n+1$. The standard proof relies on an elementary Pigeonhole principle argument, but is there a proof of it using probabilistic method?
Thoughts: if $m=n$, randomly choose $n+1$ terms and calculate the expectation of the length of the longest monotonic subsequence it contains....?
Motivation: Erdős proved a lot of stuff with probabilistic method.
Thank you.

Comment: Why to look for a rather involved proof when there is a simple one at hand?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio just for fun, as I'm curious about the boundary of probabilistic method.